# Is it possible to send APNS message without alert message? (data only)

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I'm planning some kind of APNS service which sends a password data.
But I don't want to make user's device alert any message when the app is not running.

Is this possible? And how to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you pass null as the Body of the alert then it will not display a message.
If you pass null as the sound, it will not voice a sound (or vibrate).
If you pass null as the badge, then it won't show any different badge.
And then you can pass many custom fields which the user will not know about :)

However push notifications should not be used for cruicial data since they are not always reliable. They are defined as "best effort" and may not even reach your client.

Answer (score 2):

See UIRemoteNotificationType in registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
if you don't register for UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert, no alert is displayed.